# echo -n fails with piped function

Tags: bash, unix, echo, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi2

I'm a bit of a noob so bear with me:

I have a pretty basic script to check the cpu temp of the rpi, and I need the output on a single line as a requirement for reporting to a messenger service with a webhook. The output should look something like "54.0°C,129.2°F". I know the switch to append to existing line with echo, -n, but because I am piping the Fahrenheit conversion to the bash calc (BC) I get a syntax error if i try to start that line with "echo -n etc."

I also realize that I don't really need to print the °C and °F, but i demand luxury!

Here's my script (which works fabulous if i don't try to cram it all on the same line):

```
#!/bin/bash
(
cpuTemp0=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
cpuTemp1=$(($cpuTemp0/1000))
cpuTemp2=$((cpuTemp0/100))
cpuTempM=$(($cpuTemp2 % cpuTemp1))
#date
#echo cpu temp in °C and °F
echo -n $cpuTemp1"."$cpuTempM
echo -n "°C,"
echo -n "$cpuTemp1 * 1.8 + 32"|bc
echo "°F"
) > /home/pi/bin/tlog
```

the error I receive there is:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

So the question is this; how do I get the °F on the same line as the conversion formula without borking the |bc function? I am positive the |bc is the issue as the script runs fine if I remove it, but it doesn't do the math for me. =(

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, `bc` wants a properly terminated line. So why don't we just give it one?

We can rearrange your code to do all the computation first and then do a single echo at the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

cpuTemp0=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
cpuTemp1=$(($cpuTemp0/1000))
cpuTemp2=$((cpuTemp0/100))
cpuTempM=$(($cpuTemp2 % cpuTemp1))
tempF=$(echo "$cpuTemp1 * 1.8 + 32"|bc)

echo -n "${cpuTemp1}.${cpuTempM}°C,${tempF}°F" > /home/pi/bin/tlog
```